# Beautiful Soup + textwrap for email parsing

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've got an email that looks like a whole load of this:

```
<p>Something something</p>
  <p>Something else</p>
  <a href="www.blahblah.com">Link</a>
```

So when I just grab the text using beautifulsoup, I get the following:

```
Something something
   Something else
   Link
```

...but I want to get rid of the indentation. I am trying to use textwrap.dedent, but that doesn't change the result. Also - how do I keep the link?

Current code:

```
no_html_message = BeautifulSoup(message).get_text()
formatted_message = textwrap.dedent(no_html_message)
```

UPDATE:
ran print repr(no_html_message) and all the indented lines have actual whitespace before them...i.e...

`\r\n        content`

Comment: Please reduce your original program to the shortest possible complete program that demonstrates your problem. Then copy-paste that short, complete program into your question. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Using your example code, the indentation is fine when printed:

```
html = """
<p>Something something</p>
  <p>Something else</p>
  <a href="www.blahblah.com">Link</a>
  """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.get_text()
Something something
Something else
Link
```

But if you have whitespace just use `strip`

```
BeautifulSoup(html).get_text().strip()

html = """
<p>    Something something</p>
  <p>Something else</p>
  <a href="www.blahblah.com">Link</a>
  """
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.get_text()
    Something something # whitespace
Something else
Link

print soup.get_text().strip() # no whitespace
Something something
Something else
Link
```

Comment: sorry, not sure how this helps me get rid of the indentation?

Comment: @sacshu, I  was editing, you must be  getting indentation from whitespace, just use strip

Comment: yeah i've tried strip it still doesn't work, although just printing the beautifulsoup(html) spits out a nicely formatted html file, so not sure why get_text() isn't returning something without whitespace. It's almost as if it's replacing where the tags were with whitespace.

Comment: there must be more to your code, there should be no indentation problem from what you have posted, `print repr() ` on the get_text() output to see what is in there

Answer (score 0):

One solution will be replacing instances of newline followed by spaces with newline.

```
import re
...
...
...
actual_text = soup.get_text()
unintended_text = re.sub('\n[ ]*', '\n', actual_text)
print(unintended_text)
```